# How to make a layout with a triangular protrustion on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i would like to know how i can make a layout like this on Android. I could use a LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation and put 2 Linear Layouts, the first(The Red one) with 1 of weight and the other (The white one), with 2 of weight and inside them i would put some Text Views and so on, but my main question is: How can i put in the xml a code to make this little red triangle appear, that's my question, because, without it, it is easy to make this layout, but i don't know how to put a geometric shape like this in an layout. Could you give me some suggestions? You don't need to put code if you don't want to, ideas are enough :)  Thanks in advance.

[image: Layout Image]

Comment: Add more details what you need todo, from you image it is not clear what are you looking for

Comment: Ok, i will edit my post

Answer (score 2):

I would use `ConstraintLayout`. In general, it is the best choice for complex layouts like these. Below is my attempt at reproducing this layout; I haven't bothered with perfect colors or typefaces, but the general structure is there.

**Layout XML**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:background="#f00">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/redBg"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#f00"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/caret"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/caret"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/redBg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/redBg"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/redBg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
            tools:text="26/04/2017"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/redBg"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/redBg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/subtitle"
            tools:text="Amanha"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:textColor="#f00"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/caret"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
            tools:text="1 Mililitro"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:textColor="#f00"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/caret"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/description"
            tools:text="Amoxilina"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/oval"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:textColor="#f00"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/caret"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:text="08:00"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:textColor="#f00"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:text="+detalhes"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Caret vector**

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFff0000"
        android:pathData="M0 0L24 12L0 24z"/>
</vector>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ben P, you helped me a lot. God bless you